# How to share files between different web application

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I have some images and PDFs which has to be shared between different web applications hosted on same IIS.
I have tried by creating a separate virtual directory and used the path in both applications.

Is there any other better way of doing this?

Comment: What's wrong with the virtual directory solution? Why are you not happy with that?

Comment: I don't know much about network, but client is saying it is slow due to DNS translations.

Comment: I have found http://www.hosting.com/support/nas/add-nas-as-the-virtual-directory-of-an-iis-site which is something similar to what i need.

Answer (score 0):

If it's for a website, is there a reason you couldn't just directly reference them through http?  So on Domain 1:

```
<a href="domain1/doc1.pdf">Document 1 on domain 1</a>
```

And then on your second domain (domain 2):

```
<a href="domain1/doc1.pdf">Document 1 on domain 2</a>
```

Either way, are there so many of these resources that it's worth the trouble not to just upload separately to each app?  That way you wouldn't be creating dependencies.